# Select sum of total where the date lies between two dates does not get displayed

Tags: php, sql, date, select

I m trying to do a query where it should give me the sum of the column name table, where the timestamp lies between two dates.

Heres my SQL query:

```
$year_start = strtotime('2018-01-01');
$year_end = strtotime('2018-12-31 23:59:59.000');

$query = "SELECT SUM(total) FROM buchungen WHERE datum>='".$year_start."' AND 
datum<='".$year_end."'";
```

And then I try to echo the result like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row["total"];
```

Comment: Please share the data structure for the table buchungen .

Comment: How you store dates in this table ? As date or string ?

Answer (score 0):

A query expects that dates will be in text

```
$year_start = '2018-01-01';
$year_end = '2018-12-31 23:59:59.000;

$query = "SELECT SUM(total) 
          FROM buchungen 
          WHERE datum>='$year_start' 
          AND datum<='$year_end'";
```

Also in your test there is no column called `total`, by default that column would be called `SUM(total)` unless you rename the column like this

```
$year_start = '2018-01-01';
$year_end = '2018-12-31 23:59:59.000;

$query = "SELECT SUM(total) as total 
          FROM buchungen 
          WHERE datum>='$year_start' 
          AND datum<='$year_end'";
```

Comment: ..and `$row["SUM(total)"]`?

Comment: @JustBaron Ah, thanks, was working on the edit at the time

Answer (score 0):

You must format date to sql format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

Something like

```
$year_start = date("YYYY-mm-dd", strtotime('2018-01-01'));
```